# Retrieve a row of data with the most recent date when another row <> 'X' in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database of customers who have an effective date and end date of their membership, both separate columns. The data is a bit dirty, however, and a customer can have multiple rows of data, only one of which is their most recent membership record. A member is considered "active" if they have an end date that = NULL.

The data looks somewhat like this:

```
Name         ID          Membership_Effective_Date     Membership_End_Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob           1                 1/1/2020                           NULL
Bob           1                 1/1/2017                           1/2/2017
Bob           1                 1/1/2017                           9/1/2018
Kim           2                 1/1/2019                           1/1/2020
Kim           2                 1/1/2019                           12/31/2019
Susan         3                 1/1/2018                           12/31/2018
Susan         3                 1/1/2019                           1/1/2019
Larry         4                 1/1/2020                           1/1/2020
```

I need to retrieve the most recent membership end date for a list of customers that are both inactive and active.

My desired results should look like this:

`Name         ID          Membership_Effective_Date     Membership_End_Date
Bob           1                 1/1/2020                           NULL
Kim           2                 1/1/2019                           1/1/2020
Susan         3                 1/1/2018                           12/31/2018
Larry         4                 1/1/2020                           1/1/2020`

I have been able to do this without a problem for customers that have both a row with a Membership_End_Date date value and a Membership_End_Date row with a NULL value (Bob), and customers that have multiple rows with only date values (Kim).

The challenge I am having is with data like Susan and Larry. They both have rows that contain date values where Membership_Effective_Date = Membership_End_Date. In Larry's case that is the only row of data he has. And in Susan's case the dates in the row where Membership_Effective_Date = Membership_End_Date is greater than the other row so my current query will pick it up automatically.

The problem is that I need to basically write a query that says if a customer has multiple rows of data and one row where Membership_Effective_Date = Membership_End_Date then chose the second most recent line of data. However, if a customer only has one row of data and that row only contains values where Membership_Effective_Date = Membership_End_Date then choose that one.

I can't figure out how to do this without removing Larry from the data pull completely and I need to include him and similar customers.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show us the results that you expect, and your existing query.

Comment: Can you explain better what you are doing?  You mention active and inactive memberships, but there is no column that specifies this.  Then, having the two dates be the same seems to mean something, but it is unclear what.

Comment: You can your `row_number()` with partition to get required result.

Comment: "A member is considered "active" if they have an end date that = NULL." So Inactive members are members with an end date of some date. Edited to include the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `row_number()` and a conditional sort:

```
select name, id, membership_effective_date, membership_end_date
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by id 
            order by
                case when membership_end_date is null then 0 else 1 end,
                case when membership_end_date <> membership_effective_date then 0 else 1 end,
                membership_end_date desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

The trick lies in the `order by` clause of `row_number()`: it gives priority to rows whose end date is null, then to rows whose end date is not equal to the start date, then to the greatest end date. You can run the subquery separately to see how the row number is assigned.

With this information at hand, all that is left to do is filter on the top ranked record per group.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64ca3b707a67dbd1c66c837073c9200b)**:

```
name  | id | membership_effective_date | membership_end_date
:---- | -: | :------------------------ | :------------------
Bob   |  1 | 2020-01-01                | null               
Kim   |  2 | 2019-01-01                | 2020-01-01         
Susan |  3 | 2018-01-01                | 2018-12-31         
Larry |  4 | 2020-01-01                | 2020-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

> wonder what make you think that your code is better

First of all,with due respect,no offence to any one.

```
order by
    case when membership_end_date is null then 0 else 1 end,
    case when membership_end_date <> membership_effective_date then 0 else 1 end,
      membership_end_date desc
```

I have no idea how the real data look like.

I will avoid `Row_Number` and `Inequakity Operator` if I have lot of rows to process.

`Inequakity Operator` often Scan complete table to check `Inequakity` condition.
I am sure about it.

That too `Inequakity Operator` in `Order by` clause along with Case Statement and `Row_Number`.

This may overwhelm `Sql Optimizer`.

I am not saying I always avoid `Row_Number`

Also you have not mention anything about `Membership_Effective_Date`

Try below script with various sample data,

```
    create table customers1(Name varchar(40),  ID int
    , Membership_Effective_Date datetime, Membership_End_Date datetime)
    insert into customers1 values
    ('Bob',           1    ,'2020-01-01' ,       NULL)
    ,('Bob',           1    ,'2017-01-01' ,     '1/2/2017')
    ,('Bob',           1    ,'2017-01-01' ,   '9/1/2018')
    ,('Kim',           2  ,'2019-01-01' ,   '1/1/2020')
    ,('Kim',           2   ,'2019-01-01' ,  '12/31/2019')
    ,('Susan',         3  ,'2018-01-01' ,  '12/31/2018')
    ,('Susan',         3  ,'2019-01-01' ,  '1/1/2019')
    ,('Larry',         4   ,'2020-01-01' ,   '1/1/2020')

SELECT ID
    ,NAME
    ,Membership_Effective_Date
    ,Membership_End_Date
INTO #temp
FROM customers1
WHERE Membership_End_Date IS NULL
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)

SELECT ID
    ,NAME
    ,Membership_Effective_Date
    ,Membership_End_Date
FROM #temp

UNION ALL

SELECT t.ID
    ,t.NAME
    ,min(t.Membership_Effective_Date) AS Membership_Effective_Date
    ,max(t.Membership_End_Date) AS Membership_End_Date
FROM customers1 t
WHERE Membership_End_Date IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #temp ac
        WHERE ac.ID = t.ID
        )
GROUP BY t.ID
    ,t.NAME
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)


drop table #temp
drop table customers1
```

Yes you are right earlier when I was using CTE it would have `Scan` atleast twice.

Now I am using `#temp` table but idea is same as earlier.

More or less I stick with this idea only.

Comment: I wonder what make you think that your code is better while it is probably worse for most cases. I highly recommend to check the execution plan, and the statistics of IO. Assuming we have no indexes (since the op did not provided any DDL) then your code will probably scan the table three times and will need to use a join or nested loop. Can you elaborate why you avoid using Row_Number

Comment: Sry but in the forums I never know whom I am speaking with so I have to make assumption based only on what we have here and this mean that I might made a mistake... With that being said, I must ask you if you have any knowledge regarding Execution Plan, SQL Server statistics, and monitoring performance since your query is really bad (understatement). First of all you totally changed the query which I responded to which make my comment irrelevant which is the main reason I have stackoverflow! We cannot have a discussion if you change the history.  Secondly your new query is really (REALLY) bad.

Comment: Unfortunately stackoverflow system does not fit to have a discussion. We cannot even upload images to responses or have any format text or formatted code. @KumarHarsh , I can only recommend (1) to check for more information on how to monitor performance in SQL Server. (2) Do not avoid using something just because you do not like it, and more important is not to try to force your point at all costs while you shut down yourself from actually check out the other options. *Good Luck* and well done for helping others in the forums